# Facing SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500 in azure-pipeline

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-pipelines

I have configures pipeline in Azure-Devops and configured self-hosted agent for the same. When executing it does open the browser and fails with sessionNotCreatedException.

When I execute the same code using STS or eclipse tool, it executes successfully.

facing below exception:
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Microsoft Edge failed to start: exited normally.
(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from msedge location C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe is no longer running, so msedgedriver is assuming that msedge has crashed.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following things to fix the issue:

1. In your code, add one or all of below arguments to the Edge options.

   - **`--remote-debugging-port=<port>`**
   - **`--headless`**
2. Specify the actual path of **`msedgedriver`**. For example.

   ```
   self.driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path='path/to/msedgedriver')
   ```
3. Your code might run a redundant Edge Driver copy. Try to search for any redundant Edge Driver with the keywords such as "**`msedgedriver`**" or "**`MicrosoftWebDriver`**" to locate older versions and delete them.
4. Back up your **`User Data`** folder in a new folder within the same directory. Then use that new folder to run the selenium tests.

Comment: tried this but isn't working